# Extract Display name and description Attribute from within a HTML helper

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-mvc-2, attributes, html-helper

I am building a custom `HTML.LabelFor` helper that looks like this :

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, Boolean showToolTip)
{
  var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, self.ViewData);
  ...
}
```

To be able to get the proper name for the property I am using the following code :

```
metadata.DisplayName
```

And on the property of the ModelView class I got :

```
[DisplayName("Titel")]
```

The problem is that I also need a description. There is an Attribute called Display and that has Name and Description but I do not see how to extract this with the metadata variable in the above code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Disclaimer: The following works only with ASP.NET MVC 3 (see the update at the bottom if you are using previous versions)

Assuming the following model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Description = "some description", Name = "some name")]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And the following view:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeProperty, true) %>
```

Inside your custom helper you could fetch this information from the metadata:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
    bool showToolTip
)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, self.ViewData);
    var description = metadata.Description; // will equal "some description"
    var name = metadata.DisplayName; // will equal "some name"
    // TODO: do something with the name and the description
    ...
}
```

Remark: Having `[DisplayName("foo")]` and `[Display(Name = "bar")]` on the same model property is redundant and the name used in the `[Display]` attribute has precedence in `metadata.DisplayName`.

---

UPDATE:

My previous answer won't work with ASP.NET MVC 2.0. There are a couples of properties that it is not possible to fill by default with `DataAnnotations` in .NET 3.5, and `Description` is one of them. To achieve this in ASP.NET MVC 2.0 you could use a custom model metadata provider:

```
public class DisplayMetaDataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, 
        Type containerType,
        Func<object> modelAccessor, 
        Type modelType, 
        string propertyName
    )
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        var displayAttribute = attributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (displayAttribute != null)
        {
            metadata.Description = displayAttribute.Description;
            metadata.DisplayName = displayAttribute.Name;
        }
        return metadata;
    }
}
```

which you would register in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DisplayMetaDataProvider();
}
```

and then the helper should work as expected:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
    bool showToolTip
)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, self.ViewData);
    var description = metadata.Description; // will equal "some description"
    var name = metadata.DisplayName; // will equal "some name"
    // TODO: do something with the name and the description
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is not working, the DisplayName and Description is null? Pleas note that this is in MVC2 and not MVC3. If I got it right your solution will only work in MVC3?

Comment: @SnowJim, yes, there are a couples of properties that it is not possible to fill by default with `DataAnnotations` in .NET 3.5, and Description is one of them. In .NET 4.0 it should work.

Comment: @SnowJim, please see my UPDATE for a workaround in ASP.NET MVC 2.

Comment: This is one of the most comprehensive answers I have come accross, so +1. Thank you @DarinDimitrov!