# How do I access atributes of Properties in the model from strongly typed custom HtmlHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a view that is strongly typed and its model is of type `LogOnModel`. That `LogOnModel` has anotated properties like this one:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your password")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password", Description = "Your secreet password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

All of them has `Display` anotation with `Display.Descripion` property set.
I want to create `HtmlHelper` extension method that will output `<span>` containg the value of `Display.Description` property.

So for example if I called my extension method `DescriptionFor` than this code:

```
<%: Html.DescriptionFor(m => m.Password) %>
```

should produce following html: `<span>Your secreet password</span>`

Thanks for all ideas and code.

Comment: I would be very happy if you left a comment if something is not clear in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [Extract Display name and description Attribute from within a HTML helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973830/extract-display-name-and-description-attribute-from-within-a-html-helper)

```
public static MvcHtmlString DescriptionFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, self.ViewData);
    var description = metadata.Description; // will equal "Your secreet password"
    var name = metadata.DisplayName; // will equal "Password"
    // TODO: do something with the name and the description
    ...
}
```

MSDN : [ModelMetadata Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.aspx)