# MVC Razor retrieve Description text from Model in HTML helper class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, extension-methods, html-helper

Okay I have searched it long enough to not find this anywhere on the net. So here is  my question, in asp.net MVC (5.1) razor the default helper we can use DisplayNameFor to get the `Name` value from `Display` attribute is there anything similar for retrieving `Description`?

```
[Display(Name = "First Name", Description="What is your first name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

E.g.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.FirstName)
```

Comment: you may refer to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578495/how-do-i-display-the-displayattribute-description-attribute-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use `LabelFor` and try below code.

```
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, 
    new{title=ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<Models.Profile, string>
    (m => m.FirstName, ViewData).Description})
```