# How to get the value of a ModelMetadata in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razorengine, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a project that is written with `C#` on the top of ASP.NET Core 5.0 framework.

I am trying to render the razor views manually by accessing the data directly using `ModelMetadata`. In a view, I want to  iterate through all the properties in the `Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata` and get the value of each property manually.

In the old ASP.NET MVC, I use to be able to access the value using the `Model` property on the `ModelMetadata`. With ASP.NET Core however, it seems that we have to get an instance of a `ModelExplorer` to be able to access the value of the `ModelMetadata`

Here is what I tried

```
foreach (ModelMetadata propertyMetadata in Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    ModelExplorer explorer = propertyMetadata.GetModelExplorerForType(propertyMetadata.ModelType, null);

    // do something with explorer.Model

    // I also tried 
    ModelExplorer explorer2 = html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetModelExplorerForType(propertyMetadata.ModelType, null);
}
```

The explorer is returning the correct ModelType of the property but `explorer.Model` or `explorer2.Model` are always null in this case.

How do I correctly create the `ModelExplorer` which will give me a model value?

Comment: Hi @Jay,I could not use `Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties` in asp.net core.How did you use that?Maybe you could check this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/59000216/11398810.

Comment: @Rena thanks for your help. I figured it out. Please check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I can get the value using the delegate `PropertyGetter`

Here is an example of what I did.

```
@{
    IEnumerable<ModelMetadata> properties = metadata.Properties.Where(metadata => metadata.ShowForDisplay).OrderBy(metadata => metadata.Order);
}

@foreach(var property in properties)
{
    <span>@(property.PropertyGetter(Model))</span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(p => p.PropertyGetter(Model) != null)) {
        <p><b>@property.GetDisplayName()</b> <i>@(property.IsEnumerableType ? string.Join(',', property.PropertyGetter(Model)) : property.PropertyGetter(Model))</i></p>
    }
```