# Can a DataAnnotation.UIHInt be used in a GET view

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Can `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.UIHInt` be used in a `GET` view:

Specified in `application.json`:

```
{
  "ApplicationSettings": {
    "ApplicationName":  "My Application"
  }
  ...
}
```

`ApplicationSettings` class:

```
public class ApplicationSettings
{
    [UIHint("The name of the application displayed in nav bar")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

Populated in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // retrieve the 'ApplicationSettings' section of the appsettings.json file
  var applicationSettings = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings");
  services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(applicationSettings);
  ...
}
```

Added (somehow) to `/Home/About`:

```
<h3>ApplicationSettings</h3>
<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>ApplicationName</dt>: <dd>@ApplicationSettings.Value.ApplicationName</dd>
    <????>
...
</div>
```

Displayed in HTML:

```
ApplicationSettings

ApplicationName: My Application
The name of the application displayed in nav bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first, you're using `UIHint` wrong. It's intended for specifying a view that will be used by `DisplayFor`/`EditorFor`. So, in that respect, yes you can use it for display, as well, via `DisplayFor`.

However, what you're doing here is just describing what this property is for. That's a job for the `Display` attribute:

```
[Display(Name = "The name of the application displayed in nav bar")]
```

Then, you can just do:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => ApplicationSettings.Value.ApplicationName)
```

However, even this isn't *technically* what you want. More likely than not, you still want the display name to be something like `Application Name`, and this should truly be descriptive text in addition to that. The `Display` attribute *does* have a `Description` property you can use for that:

```
[Display(Name = "Application Name", Description = "The name of the application displayed in nav bar")]
```

However, there's no built-in way to actually display that `Description`, unfortunately. There's [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35294035/654031) that contains an extension you can add for that though.

> ```
> public static class HtmlExtensions
> {
>     public static IHtmlContent DescriptionFor<TModel, TValue>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
>     {
>         if (html == null)
>             throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(html));
>         if (expression == null)
>             throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
>
>         var modelExplorer = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData, html.MetadataProvider);
>         if (modelExplorer == null)
>             throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to get model explorer for {ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)}");
>
>         return new HtmlString(modelExplorer.Metadata.Description);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Courtesy: Wouter Huysentruit