# Obtaining [Description]'s attribute value in CSHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to use in cshtml description of property/field from `Description` attribute

Is it possible to do it as easily as with `DisplayName` by using `@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => ...)` or I have to "extract it"

```
public class Test
{
    [Description("Test description")]
    public bool Name { get; set; }
}
```

I've been trying with something like that, but without any success

```
var desc = typeof(Test)
.GetCustomAttributes(false)
.ToDictionary(a => a.GetType().Name, a => a);
```

or

```
typeof(Test).Attributes

typeof(Test).GetCustomAttributesData();
```

Comment: Probably you might want to look for and try solutions for [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578495/how-do-i-display-the-displayattribute-description-attribute-value/18886645), since your `DescriptionAttribute` is essentially used like `DisplayAttribute`.

Comment: No, there is no way to quickly and easily get the `Description` of a `DescriptionAttribute` - but you can write an extension method on `HtmlHelper` called `DescriptionFor` that encapsulates looking up this metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write a custom HtmlHelper for that:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlContent DescriptionFor<TModel, TValue>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));

        DescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute = null;
        if (expression.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
        {
            descriptionAttribute = memberExpression.Member
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }

        return new HtmlString(descriptionAttribute?.Description ?? string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use `HtmlString` since this will treat the description value as HTML code and not encode special characters that appear within. For example, this will not be escaped but interpreted as html: `[Description("You can add code like <script>alert('Not escaped');</script>")]`

Comment: The value of that `DescriptionAttribute` is not entered by a client, but you right, it's better to encode its contents. @NineBerry

Comment: This probably can do the work for you ``var result = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(descriptionAttribute?.Description ?? string.Empty);``

Comment: Just return `string` instead of `IHtmlContent`. That is what `DisplayNameFor` does in ASP.net core. ASP.net will then take care of using the correct encoding mechanism. Different encoding will be required depending on where in the HTML source the content is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with this code:

```
public static IHtmlContent DescriptionFor<TModel, TValue>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    if (html == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(html));
    if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));

    var modelExplorer = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData, html.MetadataProvider);
    if (modelExplorer == null) throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to get model explorer for {ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)}");

    var metadata = (DefaultModelMetadata)modelExplorer?.Metadata;

    if (metadata == null)
    {
        return new HtmlString(string.Empty);
    }

    var text = (metadata
                .Attributes
                .Attributes // yes, twice
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute)
                ?.Description;

     var output = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text ?? string.Empty);

     return new HtmlString(output);
}
```

Comment: You should not use `HtmlString` since this will treat the description value as HTML code and not encode special characters that appear within. For example, this will not be escaped but interpreted as html: `[Description("You can add code like <script>alert('Not escaped');</script>")]`

Comment: @NineBerry Check now ``"<script>alert('test')</script>"`` is changed into ``"&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;test&#39;)&lt;/script&gt;"`` Probably it's fine now.

Comment: Just return `string` instead of `IHtmlContent`. That is what `DisplayNameFor` does in ASP.net core. ASP.net will then take care of using the correct encoding mechanism. Different encoding will be required depending on where in the HTML source the content is inserted.

Comment: @NineBerry ``Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent' ``

Comment: You need to declare the method to return type string.

Comment: @NineBerry jesus christ, sorry :D